# Is it safe to use query string in a post action?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, http, http-post, query-string

I've got two controller actions at the moment: one that displays a strongly typed view, based on an unique identifier and another one that changes the model. Here's some code to visualize what I mean:

```
[HttpGet]
[ActionName("Edit")]
public ActionResult UpdateDevice(string code)
{
    // Request the device based on the code.
    var device = GetDeviceModel(code);

    // Present the device in a view.
    return View(device);
}

[HttpPost]
[ActionName("Edit")]
public ActionResult UpdateDevice(DeviceModel model)
{
}
```

The code identifies the device, but it is also possible to change it. And that's my problem: Inside the post method I can access the *new* code using `model.Code`, but I also need to know the *old* code, to be able to change it.

I tried several alternatives, but none of them did satisfy my requirements:

- `ViewData` does not get persisted until the post.
- `TempData` is based on Sessions or Cookies – none of them I want to use at the moment.
- Hidden fields and model bindings are not an option, because they can be manipulated on client side.

Finally I tried requesting data from the query string like this:

```
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("Edit")]
public ActionResult UpdateDevice(DeviceModel model)
{
    var oldCode = Request.QueryString["code"];
}
```

And this works! But I haven't found any resources on this around the web. So my question is: Is using the query string inside a post action safe against modifications? And what (if there are any) are the conditions for this to work?

If this is not a valid way to "remember" the code, are there any alternatives?

Comment: No, it's not safe from modifications.

Comment: query string is not a safe option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the requirements you have mentioned in your question, it seems that you are looking for safety in the case. So I would say that `QueryString` is not safe. In my opinion using `Session` variables is the appropriate method that keeps your critical data in a safe location. You can use the method like this

```
[HttpGet]
[ActionName("Edit")]
public ActionResult UpdateDevice(string code)
{
    Session["code"] = code;
    ....
}

[HttpPost]
[ActionName("Edit")]
public ActionResult UpdateDevice(DeviceModel model)
{
    if (Session["code"] == null)
       throw new Exception("Error Message.");
    var code = Session["code"].ToString();
    ....
    Session["code"] = null;
}
```

Comment: Even though this is not completely what I was hoping for, your answer is the most handy compromise. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can make another property inside `DeviceModel` name `OldCode`.

and in your view you can save this value in hiddenfield like this

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.OldCode)
```

Now in controller post method you can get both the values like this.

```
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("Edit")]
public ActionResult UpdateDevice(DeviceModel model)
{
    var oldcode=model.OldCode;
    var newcode=model.Code;            
}
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: Sorry, but "Hidden fields and model bindings are not an option [...]", as I already stated above.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing submitted via a GET or a POST request is safe from modifications. While a GET query string is obviously easy to modify, it doesn't take much effort to spoof POST variables either. It sounds to me like you need to re-think your approach.

Optimally, you would do permission checking server-side to determine if the user is allowed to update the device with the passed (old) code. If they do not have permission, return an error such as an HTTP 550 code.

If you truly can't support this approach, I would suggest adding an "OldCode" field to the DeviceModel class as suggested by others, but **encrypting** it before sending it to the client. Then you can safely write it to a hidden field, and decrypt back on the server without fear of the user changing the value.